# How to compare an input image from user with a stored image on the database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to create a Windows Form application and I have images in db stored as blob objects.. can someone help me on how to compare an input image which will be accepted through linklabel and compare it with the stored images on MySql DB in C# to find the similarity between them

Comment: What do you mean by similarity. Do you want to check if their exactly the same or do you want to check if image 1 shows a cat and image 2 shows a dog the're similar because they both show an image of an animal or they're different because it's a different animal?

Comment: I just want to check if both are exactly the same images

Comment: Then just compare them byte by byte.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39980/is-there-a-faster-way-to-compare-if-2-images-are-the-same

Comment: @Blorgbeard can you help me on how to proceed in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try file hash code. You can store the original file hash code in the DB with the data and compare it against the input image. If it's the same image they should have the same hash value.

Comment: Thanks..it was lot easier than comparing the images :)